# can anyone teach me how to make android notification that occur from trigger SQLITE db event?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, database-trigger

i am currently making an android application. then i need to make a notification that only occur when there is certain event occur like insert or update.

what i want to try is how to use SQLITE trigger to make the notification occur on the android apps whenever user insert or update their data

thanks.

Comment: `can anyone teach me ...` **NO**. This is not a learning place.

Comment: where is it then besides this site?

Comment: This site works like: **1** - You show your broken code and the error you get. **2** - Someone will try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `TRIGGER` syntax

[image]

and you will discover there's no place to do it (unless you create your own function).

However, your application is the only one invoking `insert()` or `update()` so you know even before the trigger is invoked whether you want to send a notification. Then, do it where you invoke these methods.

Comment: ah i see then if this trigger used to call a function to invoke android notification it's still possible right?